# jQuery.mThumbnailScroller can't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery thumbnail scroller. 
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/

i have linked .js file and css file in head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/scrollermaster/jquery.mThumbnailScroller.css">
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script href="plugins/scrollermaster/jquery.mThumbnailScroller.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(window).load(function(){
                    $("#my-thumbs-list").mThumbnailScroller({ axis:"x" });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

In body ..

```
<div id="my-thumbs-list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="image-1-link"><img src="/path/to/image-1-file.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="image-2-link"><img src="/path/to/image-2-file.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="image-3-link"><img src="/path/to/image-3-file.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="image-4-link"><img src="/path/to/image-4-file.jpg" /></a></li>
    <!-- and so on... -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code can't work for me. 
google chorme (Console ) display this error

> index.php:98 Uncaught
>   TypeError: $(...).mThumbnailScroller is not a function